# Overseas ERP consequences

Tags: united-states, criminal-law, international, minor, turkey

A friend of mine is worried about a certain thing he did a couple of months ago. Assume he lied about his age when he was 17 (now 18), and did erotic roleplay (ERP) with another individual who also lied about their age, and claimed to be over 18. This friend of mine lives in an overseas country, for example, Turkey while the other person lives in the US.

My friend asked for their age multiple times, and asked for their birthday to confirm and actually got confirmation that they were an adult (no actual IDs were sent). There were no actual, real life pictures sent or received. Just drawings and chatting. Could my friend get into trouble for something he did when he was also a minor? Could he be arrested when he visits the US?

Thank you.

Comment: There were no actual pictures of bodies sent in this case.

Comment: Also related https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/79971/sexting-with-a-minor-overseas

Comment: Involving the same countries (possibly the same people). https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/22541/international-sexting-how-often-is-sexting-overseas-prosecuted-please-read-de

Comment: There were no actual nude photos sent or received.

Comment: Also no, I'm not related to that person. But I've read their case. The difference is that there were no actual pictures sent.

Comment: Also related https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/40446/can-one-be-prosecuted-for-sexting-a-minor-overseas?rq=1

Comment: Every related question you link is a case of sexting. I haven't sent or received any pictures.

Comment: Can someone thoroughly read my question and answer it, thanks.

Comment: While related this is not at all a duplicate because the element of images is not present

Comment: Yeah. Basically, as the question says, a friend of mine was worried because of roleplaying when he was a minor. He's now an adult, and has cut contact. But assuming from the replies, I guess he's safe?

Comment: No nude pics were shared whatsoever

Answer (score 3):

This is unlikely to give rise to criminal charges in the U.S., if the bare bone facts of the question are all that is involved.

It does not count as child pornography. But possible offenses might include contributing to the delinquency of a minor (a minor misdemeanor), or perhaps enticing a minor to travel in interstate commerce for sex, neither of which are likely to come up in a case where no travel occurs until both parties are adults. The potential offenses, unlike child pornography offenses themselves, would generally include defense for good faith mistakes regarding age.

The [situation in Turkey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LGBT_rights_in_Turkey) could be more serious. While I can't identify a particular offense, if the participants were of the same sex, even though homosexuality is not outright banned in Turkey, as it is in many predominantly Islamic countries, this could be characterized as an "offense against public morality" in Turkey.

In either a same sex or opposite sex circumstance, it might be characterized in Turkey as some form of illegal seduction, or perhaps as some implicit form of blasphemy.

Even if it didn't give rise to criminal charges, it might also be used as a basis for severe parental discipline, or as a basis for finding that someone lacked "good character" in a civil context, in either country.

Of course, unless the interaction is known, identified with real people, and brought to the attention of law enforcement, nothing would happen.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. So, there is an extremely low chance of anything coming up from this?

Comment: @a_questionierre1 Is there any reason you would think it would come to the attention of law enforcement or someone with a grudge against one of the parties?

Comment: I don't believe there is, no. I'd also like to ask if they also could get into trouble because my friend was also underaged?

Comment: If law enforcement does not get involed, I'm assuming no one could get charged, right?

Comment: @a_questionierre1 "If law enforcement does not get involed, I'm assuming no one could get charged, right?" Pretty much. If no one with the ability to enforce criminal laws learns about something, the law books don't walk off the shelves and beat you over the head.

Comment: Thank you. Is this case just something that both parties shouldn't be worried about?

Comment: @a_questionierre1 Not unless there is some specific reason to worry that isn't identified in the question.

Comment: I'm assuming you're referring to the exchange of footage of nude pictures? In that case, neither of the parties shared any of that.

Comment: @a_questionierre1 "I'm assuming you're referring to the exchange of footage of nude pictures?" No. I'm referring to any other reason that could be out there. Was there an exchange of money? Was there an attempt to manipulate someone to gain some advantage? Is there someone trying to blackmail you that knows? Or any other manner of circumstances. Law is heavily context specific, and particular fact patterns can give rise to consequences someone unfamiliar with law wasn't thinking about.

Comment: I don't think there were any exchange of money or any of that stuff. These interactions took place after they met in a roleplay environment online. The only think apart from erotic roleplay is talking about the drawn artwork of fictional characters (that are also 18+)

Could the second part raise any issues?